# Qt/c++ QGraphicsItem bound to custom Class

Tags: c++, qt, selecteditem, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I've been working on a game in C++/Qt. My game consists of some custom Classes with a pointer to a custom class picture that inherits from QGraphicsItem. The Picture class also contains a pointer back to the instance of the custom class.

Now when I add the items with the picture class to a QGraphicsScene, I want to get the selected items from that Scene, and read the pointers to their custom classes, but I don't really know a way to do this. I tried using QGraphicsScene->selectedItems() but this only returns a QList of GraphicsItems :S

Could anybody help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dynamic_cast` to cast the `QGraphicsItem`s to your custom class that inherits from QGraphicsItem when you get a list of selected items in the scene.

Example:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> list = scene->selectedItems();
for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++)
{        
    CustomItem *item = dynamic_cast<CustomItem*>(list[i]);
}
```

Comment: @CédricVandelaer I didn't say cast the QList to your custom class :) Anyway I modified the answer so it contains an example that is more clear for your purpose.

Comment: Well it works, but is there a way to preserve the pointer stored in the picture class that is derived from QGraphicsItem?

Comment: @CédricVandelaer What do you exactly mean with preserving the pointer?

Comment: in the scene there are some items selected, those are picture classes that inherit from QGraphicsItem, but they also contain a pointer. but when I first cast that itemlist to a QList<QGraphicsItem*> list like you metioned above, won't the pointer in the picture class be lost?

Comment: @CédricVandelaer What you're casting is a QGraphicsItem to your custom picture item class. After you have casted the QGraphicsItem to your own custom class item, you can access the pointer stored in your custom class. For example, if we follow the example I posted above: `item->myPointer;`.

Comment: but if that pointer already contains an adress, will that adress be lost? (and thx for the help btw)

Comment: @CédricVandelaer If it already contains an address, you can access it safely. It wont be lost during the type casting process. Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) to learn more about type casting.